# Create table with UNIQUEIDENTIFIER as PK

Tags: sql, t-sql

I have been trying (unsuccessfully) to create a table with a `UNIQUEIDENTIFIER` as the primary key. The script below will create the table just fine, however there is no PK specified. This is my first time using a UNIQUEIDENTIFIER, however. Any ideas?

**T-SQL**

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[AgentRelationshipCodes]
(
Id UNIQUEIDENTIFIER NOT NULL DEFAULT NEWID(),
RelationshipId char(3) NULL,
EffectiveDate datetime NULL,
LastChangeDate datetime NOT NULL,
LastChangeId char(6) NOT NULL,
AgtTableId int FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES AgentTransmission(ID)
);
```

**Management Studio**

[image]

Comment: Just add: `CONSTRAINT PK_AgentRelationshipCodes_ID PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED (ID)` or `CONSTRAINT PK_AgentRelationshipCodes_ID PRIMARY KEY NONCLUSTERED (ID)`

Comment: Or a bit of shorter: Add `PRIMARY KEY [CLUSTERED]` after `NEWID()`.

Comment: Does [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1565172/sql-server-how-to-maintain-guid-across-tables-in-same-db) help?

Comment: I would **strongly** advise against this set up. Have the unique identifier as your primary key by all means, but put in an identity column and make this your clustering key. Inserts get very expensive and you end up with huge fragmentation when you use unique identifiers as the clustering key (which it will be by default when you make it the primary key unless you explicitly do otherwise). If you must make it the clustering key, then use `NEWSEQUENTIALID()` as the default.

Comment: And while I think using a GUID is a horrible practice, it can be needed in some cases. However, don't use newID() use NEWSEQUENTIALID().

Comment: @GarethD Where is op saying that he wants the primary key to be clustered?

Comment: @Lamak He doesn't say he does, but he doesn't say that he doesn't want it be clustered either, and by default the primary key will be the clustering key. There is also no other good candidate for a clustering key in the table.

Comment: @GarethD Well, I read the "strongly advise against this set up" like op was already thinking of doing it, thus the "against this set up"

Comment: Using a GUID as PK is a bad practice and potentialy a time-bomb performance disaster (triggered in production if you don't perform enough stress testing). Also using a GUID can be preferred in some situations, in the particular case when the application itself is generating the Id and passing it to the DB. Sequential GUIDs can also help. For the OP scenario I can strongly advice to consider using a Int and (auto) identity. For all my colleagues I can advice to search and learn about GUID uses and pitfalls as Id.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
create table [dbo].[AgentRelationshipCodes]
(
    Id UNIQUEIDENTIFIER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY DEFAULT NEWID(),
    .
    .
    .
)
```

Repeat for the other tables.

- Answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1565172/sql-server-how-to-maintain-guid-across-tables-in-same-db) by [Christian Hayter](https://stackoverflow.com/users/115413/christian-hayter)